# Data tab and dataset in Visual Studio 2005 / 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, bids

I have built some reports in both VS 2005 and VS 2008.

In VS 2005 I have 3 tabs available on Design page -  'Preview' 'Layout' and 'Data'.

In VS 2008 I have only the 2 - 'Design' and 'Preview'

Can anyone pioint me in the correct direction as it is what is held in the **2005 tab of **'Data'**** that I am looking for in VS 2008

**This shows a very simple view of what SQL query's are being used and easily allows modification.**

I cannot find this in VS 2008 and only a 'view code' option that shows all HTML code as well???

Any help much appreciated.

(the reason for me tryng to do this is the original reports were built in VS 2005 and have been converted to VS 2008 and now need editing and it would be much easier if I had a simple view of just the SQL query's in the reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question as I believe I have found what I am looking for.

Once you have enabled the 'Report Data' toolbar you can access datasets, build new ones and also isolate each sql query that is being used in the report design for easy editing.